# Deploying C# application that has ironpython which needs standard library

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, standard-library

I wrote an app that has an `Iron Python` script, and that script needs `python` standard library. Now my `python` script looks for standard library at `C:\program files\IronPython 2.7\lib`.

The question is: what would be the best way to deploy this app? I read that there is a way to compile `python` Standard library to single `.dll`, but cannot figure out how to do that, and if I figure that out, the next question would be how to direct my script to this `dll`.

Now I set path for my script like this:

```
var paths = py.GetSearchPaths();
        paths.Add(Globals.pythonPath); // path
        py.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

Or, the other thing is just to copy entire `lib` folder into my app directory, however I couldn't make link to `/lib` folder relative... the script only works with full path to `lib` folder.

The goal is to be able to deploy my app, so it would have `app.exe` and `lib` folder in its directory + other files... or `app.exe`, `pythonSTDLib.dll` and other stuff in its directory.

Comment: Did u try this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ironpycompiler ?

Comment: When you compile your python scripts into some dll/exe, checking for imports should be resolved automatically in the dll/exe.